# Изучение реализации CRUD для MySQL

Tags: php, книги

Есть какие-нибудь интересные статьи, книжки по грамотной реализации CRUD для MySQL? 
P.S. Фреймворки не предлагать, интересует велосипедостроение.

Comment: Лично для меня вопрос выглядит примерно так - если какаето книга по завязыванию шнурков? Бантиком не предлагать!!!11АДИН11! ^^

Comment: Ну собственно я уже сделал реализацию, мне просто интересно посмотреть другие варианты. Так я новичок, мне кажется, что моя архитектура CRUD далеко не самая лучшая.

Comment: Вот все равно предложу фреймворки. Только не использовать, а читать (раз в вопросе речь о книгах). Фреймворки для php, как правило, имеют достаточно хорошо оформленный код, временами еще и обильно комментированный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про паттерн "Единица Работы" как минимум